# How to Unmarshall a Json string in Go lang to obtain value of only one key

Tags: go

So i need to decode a json string to obtain value of **key *ID*** but i was not able to find a way to only extract value of only one key so i created a struct of whole json string so that i can **unmarshal** it to extract info but i think there is some problem with my struct because i don't get any output

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)
type season struct{
    Data []seasoninfo `json:"seasoninfo"`
}
type seasoninfo struct{
    Aliases []string
    Banner string
    FirstAired string
    Id int
    Network string
    Overview string
    SeriesName string
    Slug string
    Status string
}
func main() {
    s := `{"data":[{"aliases":[],"banner":"graphical/81189-g21.jpg","firstAired":"2008-01-20","id":81189,"network":"AMC","overview":"Walter White, a struggling high school chemistry teacher, is diagnosed with advanced lung cancer. He turns to a life of crime, producing and selling methamphetamine accompanied by a former student, Jesse Pinkman, with the aim of securing his family's financial future before he dies.","seriesName":"Breaking Bad","slug":"breaking-bad","status":"Ended"},{"aliases":[],"banner":"","firstAired":"","id":356427,"network":"AMC","overview":null,"seriesName":"Breaking Bad: Original Minisodes","slug":"breaking-bad-original-minisodes","status":"Ended"},{"aliases":["Breaking Bad (ES)"],"banner":"graphical/273859-g.jpg","firstAired":"2014-06-08","id":273859,"network":"Univision","overview":"“Metastasis” is the story of a struggling high school chemistry teacher who is diagnosed with inoperable lung cancer. He turns to a life of crime, producing and selling meth with a former student in order to secure his family’s financial future before he passes away.","seriesName":"Metastasis","slug":"metastasis","status":"Ended"}]}`
    var series season
    err:=json.Unmarshal([]byte(s),&series)
    if err==nil{
        fmt.Println(series)
    } else{
        fmt.Println("wrong")
    }
}
```

Output is {[]}

https://play.golang.org/p/5jYSp4cMCok

Thanks

Comment: ``json:"seasoninfo"`` is wrong.

Comment: Either  change to ``json:"data"` or change incoming JSON to `{"seasoninfo":[{"aliases":[],"banne` so that matches key you are expecting. https://play.golang.org/p/mU5KlcBDsUk or https://play.golang.org/p/CeeEc48IyvZ at least

Comment: please can you mention a go playground link with modification....i am bit new to go

Comment: thanks a lot.....it worked

Comment: @PRAKHARKAUSHIK I posted an answer. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Yes thanks a lot!! it worked like a charm @AlexanderStaroselsky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are currently trying to match struct field `Data` to JSON property key `seasoninfo`. However your sample JSON input doesn't have `seasoninfo` as the outer property, it has `data` as an outer property. Either change `json:"seasoninfo"` to `json:"data"`:

```
type season struct{
  Data []seasoninfo `json:"data"`
}
```

Here is an an [example](https://play.golang.org/p/mU5KlcBDsUk) in action.

Or even simpler you could consider simply removing the `json:"data"` portion as `data` in the JSON matches `Data` of the struct field:

Here is an [example](https://play.golang.org/p/mYjTY4-lYmH) in action:

```
type season struct{
    Data []seasoninfo
}
```

Hopefully that helps!